# Perform string search with Linq to Entities

Tags: c#, .net, string, linq, linq-to-entities

I want to enable this function in Linq to Entities (so the filtering happens on the SQL Server)?

```
public static bool ContainsAny(this string source, StringComparison comparison,
                               IEnumerable<string> searchTerms)
{
  return searchTerms.Any(searchTerm => source.Contains(searchTerm, comparison));
}
```

My goal is search a table and limit the result by filtering a certain column with the above function, i.e. `GetContacts().Where(c => c.FullName.ContainAny(searchTerm))`.

Comment: I assume `source` should be of type `IEnumerable<string>`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, it's tricky (if possible which I don't know) to use StringComprison in Expressions and expect Linq 2 Entities to translate it to correct Sql statements.

Second, it's tricky to use a custom function like your *ContainsAny* in an Expression too.

So if I were you, the simple solution is:

```
GetContacts().Where(c => searchTerms.Any(term => c.FullName.Contains(term)))
```

which should work in EF4.

Comment: +1 for pointing out that `Any` can be used with a local sequence (which Linq-to-Sql can't do). The `StringComparison` part is not covered though.

Comment: I see. And since the default SQL string comparison is case-insensitive, that should perform just what I want it to. Anyway, if you ever find a way to get over and implement `StringComparisong` stop by and drop it here so I can include that in my extension library... Thanks dawg!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at a nuget package I have created

### http://www.nuget.org/packages/NinjaNye.SearchExtensions

This will enable the following (and more) which will return results where the search term appears in property specified

```
var result = GetContacts().Search("searchTerm", c => c.FullName);
```

For searching multiple terms you can do the following:

```
var result = GetContacts().Search(searchTerms, c => c.FullName);
```

The above will return results where any search term appears in the property

This builds up an expression tree which performs the search on the database not in memory, so only matching results are returned form the server.

For more information take a look at the **[projects GitHub page](https://github.com/ninjanye/SearchExtensions)** or my **[blog posts](http://jnye.co/posts/tagged/search-extensions)**